# How to use createNSResolver with lookupNamespaceURI directly?

Tags: javascript, firefox, xpath, namespaces

I am trying to use figure out how xpath is working in FireFox, but I am unable to resolve a simple namespace prefix. The lookupNamespaceURI keeps on returning null.

I was unable to find any working examples on the net, so I am wondering if I am using this function correctly. Any insight would be very helpful.

```all
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var testResolver = function()
            {
                var resolver = document.createNSResolver(document.documentElement);
                alert(resolver.lookupNamespaceURI('ev'));
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="testResolver()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you serve the document with an XML or XHTML MIME type e.g. `Content-Type: application/xml` or `Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml` (example at http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xml/test2011091101.xhtml). If you serve as text/html then I don't think namespace resolution will work.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following method for creating a namespace resolver for HTML document:

```
function createNSResolver(document) {
    var ns = {};
    if (document.documentElement) {
        var attrs = document.documentElement.attributes;
        for (var i = 0; i < attrs.length; ++i) {
            if (attrs[i].name.indexOf("xmlns:") == 0) {
                ns[attrs[i].name.substring(6)] = attrs[i].value;
            }
        }
    }
    var nsResolver = function nsResolver(prefix) {
        return ns[prefix] || null;
    };
    nsResolver.lookupNamespaceURI = nsResolver;
    return nsResolver;
}
```

Comment: Well, this was answered long ago (2012), I'm not sure this interface existed then :)